# Optimize SQL-Query that is using REGEXP in a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have the following situation:

Table Words:

```
| ID |   WORD |
|----|--------|
|  1 |     us |
|  2 |     to |
|  3 | belong |
|  4 |    are |
|  5 |   base |
|  6 |   your |
|  7 |    all |
|  8 |     is |
|  9 |  yours |
```

Table Sentence:

```
| ID |                                  SENTENCE |
|----|-------------------------------------------|
|  1 | <<7>> <<6>> <<5>> <<4>> <<3>> <<2>> <<1>> |
|  2 |                         <<7>> <<8>> <<9>> |
```

And i want to replace the <<(\d)>> with the equivalent word from the Word-Table.

So the result should be

```
| ID |                       SENTENCE |
|----|--------------------------------|
|  1 | all your base are belong to us |
|  2 |                   all is yours |
```

What i came up with is the following SQL-Code:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(word ORDER BY pos SEPARATOR ' ') AS sentence FROM (
    SELECT sentence.id, words.word, LOCATE(words.id, sentence.sentence) AS pos
    FROM sentence
    LEFT JOIN words
    ON (sentence.sentence REGEXP CONCAT('<<',words.id,'>>'))
    ) AS TEMP
GROUP BY id
```

I made a sqlfiddle for this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/634b8/4

The code basically is working, but i'd like to ask you pros if there is a way without a derived table or without filesort in the execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

You should make a table with one entry per word, so your sentense (sic) can be made by joining on that table. It would look something like this

```
SentenceId, wordId, location
2,          7,       1
2,          8,       2
2,          9,       3
```

They way you have it set up, you are not taking advantage of your database, basically putting several points of data in 1 table-field.

The location field (it is tempting to call it "order", but as this is an SQL keyword, don't do it, you'll hate yourself) can be used to 'sort' the sentence.

(and you might want to rename sentense to sentence?)

Comment: Hello, i appreciate your proposed solution of a normalized n-n table, the problem in my question is just not about normalizing, because i actually can't edit the current scheme where the problem derives from =)

The main question is, if this is possible without a derrived table...

Comment: The issue is that you are looking for specific features from a relational database, that you can get if you use it like one. In this case, your have several data "items" in one column, so the database cannot do much more then scan them. The only thing you might be able to do is just retrieve all the words, retrieve al the sentences, and replace them in code. Now you are not joining on a regexp, but it depends on how your data is, if this is a viable way, and probably not much of a refinement. So if you can't change the scheme, you're stuck with sub-optimal solutions :(

Comment: yeah looks like that, thats how it is actually done, i just get the sentence-table and am doing a foreach in code to retrieve the actual words afterwards, but thats kinda slow at the moment (depends on the count of sentences), well thanx anyways ;)